# SQL Query Not Getting Results

Tags: sql

What I am doing wrong here? Can anyone please help?

**1.** Use non-correlated sub-query, find the names of employees who are not working on any projects

Answer:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee_name 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT employee_id FROM projectinfo 
             WHERE project IS NOT NULL);
```

**2.** Use correlated sub-query, find the names of employees who are not working on any projects.

Answer:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM employee_name
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM project 
                WHERE project.employee_id = project_id 
                  AND projectinfo.project IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sue the `LEFT JOIN` as follows for non-correlated sub-query as follows:

```
SELECT e.* FROM employee_name  E -- is employee_name a table? if no, then use proper table name
LEFT JOIN project P
ON E.ID = P.employee_id
WHERE P.project_id IS NULL;
```

Using correlated sub-query

```
SELECT * FROM employee_name E 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM project p
  WHERE p.employee_id= e.employee_id);
```

**Note**: I have considered that the employee record is not available in the `project` table if the employee has no project assigned.

Comment: Can I also write in this way?SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emp_name NOT IN (SELECT emp_name FROM employees);

Comment: That will return nothing. And its better not to use not in

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, using sub-query how can I find the names of the employees with the highest rate? Can you please tell me? I am trying to learn.
I wrote this:
SELECT first_name,last_name, job_id, salary 
FROM employees 
WHERE rate > ALL (SELECT rate FROM employees)

Comment: @Fahima first of all you should accept this answer if it resolved your issue and second the query that you used for highest rate employee is correct but you would like to try this: `SELECT first_name,last_name, job_id, salary FROM employees WHERE rate = (SELECT max(rate) FROM employees)`